# Burninate [mvc6]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There is [mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc6) with 65 questions and no tag wiki. There is also [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc) with 1.5k questions. The [mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc6) tag should be removed and the [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc) tag be used for future questions.

Since there is a change in naming and [asp.net-mvc-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-6) is not used as the proper tag, [mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc6) could be made into a synonym.

Since there already is another tag with wiki and all questions in this tag belong to that, I assume it is ok to just retag the questions and let the [mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc6) burn.

Comment: Oh, I see that they renamed ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core. What is MVC 6? (Microsoft really is trying their hardest to make this as confusing as possible. Typical.)

Comment: @CodyGray No, ASP.NET 5 is ASP.NET Core 1.0, ASP.NET MVC 6 is ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0. Fortunately this makes is less confusing since previously the 5/6 was more confusing.